# wordpress - MIME-тип («text/html») не является допустимым для JavaScript

Tags: wordpress

Переношу wordpress с локального xampp на хостинг beget.
Импортировал БД(поставил галку отобразить MIME типы).
В файле .sql заменил пути localhost. На хосте создал новую БД и экспортировал БД.

Заменил:

define( 'DB_NAME', 'DB_NAME' );

define( 'DB_USER', 'DB_USER' );

define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_PASSWORD' );

**Как итог ошибка в консоли:** Сценарий из «http://user.beget.tech/site/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp» был загружен, хотя его MIME-тип («text/html») не является допустимым для JavaScript.

Стили не загружаются, переходы не работают.

Comment: Читай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562 и делай заново

Comment: Спасибо, выручил.